# SearchView onSearchClickListener not working

Tags: java, android, onclick, searchview

I have my SearchView set on

> android:iconifiedByDefault="false"

and I would like to track when the user first opens the Searchbar (the moment when the keyboard pops up)

This does not work:

```
searchView = findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("###", "Clicked");
    }
});
```

The code above only works when the searchbar is iconified.
I dont want a iconified searchbar, mine should be like the Instagram searchbar with a queryHint "Search here..."

Here is my XML:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    app:defaultQueryHint="Search here"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I also tried to implement onTouchListener:

```
    searchView = findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
    searchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.i("###", "Clicked ");
            return true;
        }
    });
```

but its the same, only works when clicking on the search icon.

Comment: Instead of SearchView, you can try only EditText. I think EditText.addTextChangedListener() will do the job

Answer (score 0):

Try `setOnTouchListener` here I am providing kotlin code ,you can implement similarly in java too.

```
  searchView.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener{
            override fun onTouch(v : View?, event : MotionEvent?) : Boolean {
                Log.i("tag","test")
                return  true
            }
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this also doesn't do anything.
It only works when I click on the search icon but not everywhere on the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try the `setOnFocusChangeListener` and set the focusable property to `true` in your `searchView`.

The code (it's Kotlin - I don't have a java file rn, but you can easily auto-convert it. I kept it as Java-like as possible):

```kotlin
searchView?.setOnFocusChangeListener(object: View.OnFocusChangeListener {
    override fun onFocusChange(v: View?, hasFocus: Boolean) {
        // do fancy stuff
    }
})
```

And xml:

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:defaultQueryHint="Search here"/>
```

Also, a little side note: even though it is not related to the question, but a lot of people might stumble over this question, confused why `onSearchClick` is not being executed when you start the search: The function `setOnQueryTextListener` exists therefore. You can also use it, when you want to register changes in the text, not just opening of the keyboard.